# Problemas ao recuperar o objeto do DataTable no P:Dialog

Tags: java, jsf, aplicação-web, primefaces

eu possuo um datatable que me lista todos os alunos, e tenho um botão que abre um modal, nesse modal eu quero continuar manipulando meu objeto do datatable, para isso eu uso a propriedadef:setPropertyActionListener, mas o objeto sempre vem vazio, já olhei vários tópicos aqui no fórum mas nada resolveu, se alguém puder dar um norte eu agradeço;

Ali no dialog o atributo ID sempre vem zero, ali tá meu problema mas não acho o porque.

```
Bean

@ManagedBean(name = "funcionarioMB")
@SessionScoped
public class FuncionarioMB {

private Aluno aluno;
private List<Aluno> alunosInativos;
private FuncionarioDAO fDAO = new FuncionarioDAO();

//getters and setters


//construtor
public FuncionarioMB() {
        aluno = new Aluno();
        alunosInativos = fDAO.ListarAlunosInativos();
}

//Tela

        <h:form id="form" prependId="false">
        <p:dataTable var="aluno" value="#{funcionarioMB.alunosInativos}">

             .... OUTRAS COLUNAS....

            <div class="ui-g-12">
            <p:column style="width:60px">
           <p:commandButton value="Recusar" update="confirmaRecusa" oncomplete="PF('confirmaRecusa').show()" styleClass="btn btn-danger btn-block" >
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{aluno}" target="#{funcionarioMB.aluno}" />
             </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
            </div>
            </p:dataTable>

//Dialog

<p:dialog header="Motivo" widgetVar="confirmaRecusa" modal="true" id="confirmaRecusa" height="200" width="200">
<p:inputText id="email" maxlength="200" value="#{funcionarioMB.email.assunto}" styleClass="form-control" required="true" requiredMessage="Necessário informar um motivo" />
<h:outputText value="#{funcionarioMB.aluno.id}" />
<p:commandButton value="Aceitar" id="aceitar" action="#{funcionarioMB.recusarAluno(aluno)}" styleClass="btn btn-success btn-block" ajax="false" />
</p:dialog></h:form>`
```

Comment: Tenta fazer o seguinte: `<p:commandButton value="Recusar" action="#{funcionarioMB.setAluno(aluno)}" update="confirmaRecusa" oncomplete="PF('confirmaRecusa').show()" styleClass="btn btn-danger btn-block" />`. Outra coisa, acho que `action="#{funcionarioMB.recusarAluno(aluno)}"` não vai funcionar e nem precisa passar aluno como parâmetro pois o aluno já está setado no funcionarioMB.